# Homology of a finite-dimensional CW Complex is free - Typo in the statement?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have the following question regarding an exercise in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (2.1.22):

Prove by induction on dimension the following about the homology of a finite-dimensional CW complex $X$:
If $X$ has dimension $n$ then $H_i(X) = 0, i > n$ and $H_n(X)$ is **free.**

Is **free** perhaps a typo and we are supposed to show $H_n(X)$ is **free abelian**? I have two reasons to believe so:

1. I already walk into problems for $n=0$, because if $X$ is more than one $0-$cell, say $k$ many, then $H_0(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^k $ But for $k>1$ this is not free, but it is a free abelian group.
2. Since I was able to start the induction for the statement free abelian, I tried to finish it also with that in mind and it works:

For if the (changed) statement is true for $n-1$, we have the les of a pair

$$\cdots 0 \rightarrow H_{n+1}(X^{n-1}) \rightarrow H_{n+1}(X^n) \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots$$

Where I get the 0 because $(X^n, X^{n-1})$ is a good pair, hence the homology group equals $$\tilde{H_i}(X^n/X^{n-1}) = \tilde{H_i}(\vee^k S^n) = 0, \text{for } i > n.$$ So we get isomorphism for $H_{n+1}(X^{n-1}) \cong H_{n+1}(X^n)$, which is 0 by the hypothesis. One section down in the les we get

$$0 \rightarrow H_n(X^n) \rightarrow \tilde{H_n}(\vee^k S^n) = \mathbb{Z}^k \rightarrow \cdots$$ and we see that $H_n(X^n)$ injects into $\mathbb{Z}$, so is a subgroup. The subgroups are free abelian, but I don't think I can guarantee that it is $\mathbb{Z}$, which would be (the only possible?) free group that is a subgroup.

Or is it that we can use free and free abelian when the context is clear? (I admit free group has not appeared in chapter 2 afaik but it is an own section in chapter 1 and we have made a particular effort to distinguish between free abelian groups and free groups, so this strikes me as odd and other excercises on the same page explicitly state to show that something is a free abelian group.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a typo, but you are correct that "free Abelian" is the meaning. It's not a typo since homology operates entirely within the context of Abelian groups (categories) and the adjective "free" is only used to mean "free (Abelian)". You can view "free" as a more general (category-theoretic..) word, and since we work with Abelian groups the qualifier "Abelian" is implicit and doesn't need to be said explicitly.

Comment: So another exercise could have dropped the abelian "Show that for the subspace $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{R}$, the relative homology group $H_1$ is free abelian" as well (Ex. 2.1.18)?

Comment: @Taleofwoe Yes. Homology groups are always Abelian and can never be free in the nonabelian sense. Except for the trivial case of $\Bbb Z$

Comment: (Or the trivial case of $0$.)